# Will this 800 x 480 resolution display be readable/usable?

Tags: hardware, display

I have small 9-inch 800x480 display with RCA port and I would like to use it with the Raspberry Pi booting Raspbian.

How readable/usable it will be? Does it require scrolling to see other parts of desktop or does it show full desktop?

Where I could find video showing Raspberry with 800x480 display?

Comment: You didn't post a link to the display you would like to use.  How are we supposed to figure this out?  Also, how readable and useable it will be could be considered opinion-based.

Comment: The text console display size is detected by the kernel.  The GUI desktop should autoconfigure itself based on the same characteristics, or (worst case scenario) you'll need to configure it yourself, which is not that hard. Optionally, you can create a desktop *bigger* than the screen and scroll around it -- although I am not sure if all desktop environments (aka "DE's"), including the raspbian default LXDE support this, there are at least some window managers (aka "WM's") that do.

Answer (score 4):

A 9-inch screen is as large as most netbook screens, so it should be fine. it would be better than a small screen like this: [image]

and would be larger than this 640x480 screen:
[image]

A tutorial of interest can be found [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/11/cheap-miniature-lcd-screen/), with how you can set-up the display etc, and also if you run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

You can configure the text size, and make it larger, like in the top photo.